# Issue with smart_listing gem: ExecJS::RuntimeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use smart_listing gem to retrieve data from a table. But i have multiple issues. I realise that i do not have errors only when I delete the following lines from my "views/layouts/application.html.erb".

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

But then that will screw up my entire app. 
Does anyone knows a way around ? It seems that this gem has many issues.

my controller looks like:

```
class DistribsController < ApplicationController

  include SmartListing::Helper::ControllerExtensions
  helper  SmartListing::Helper

  def index
    smart_listing_create :contacts, Contact.all, partial: "distribs/list"
  end
end
```

my _list.html.haml looks like:

```
- unless smart_listing.empty?
  %table.table.table-striped
    %thead
      -# Second argument of sortable is sorted attribute name
      %th.col-md-3= smart_listing.sortable "Name", "name"
      %th.col-md-3= "Phone"
      %th.col-md-4= smart_listing.sortable "Location", "location"
      %th
        %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-shopping-cart{title: "Has credit card?"}
      %th.col-md-2= smart_listing.sortable "Wallet saldo", "saldo"
    %tbody
      - smart_listing.collection.each do |o|
        %tr
          -# User row goes here...

  = smart_listing.paginate
  = smart_listing.pagination_per_page_links
- else
  %p.warning No records!
```

index.html.haml looks like:

= smart_listing_render :contacts
index.js.erb looks like:

```
<%= smart_listing_update :contacts %>
```

Comment: You don't need to use `javascript_include_tag "application "` twice, it should be included only once

Comment: Ok, that one i just fixed, but I think the problem is elsewhere. Thank you @Vasilisa for highlighting.